# How to limit spaces and breaks lines in Draft JS?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, reactjs, draftjs

I am trying to clean my html content before save it to my database. I need to limit both vertical and horizontal spaces. I don't want to allow more than 1 space in both cases.

However, the javascript `replace()` function seems to be inappropriate.

```
content = content.replace(/(&nbsp;){2,}/gm," ") //horizontal spaces

content = content.replace(/(<p><br><\/p>){2,}/gm,'\v') //Vertical spaces
```

None of the above operations tried above seems to be working. Moreover html tags are not recognized in my `regex` whereas text I can replace text inside them. Yet my html content has been successfully converted into string.

How can I `trim` these additional spaces or at least prevent user to make multiple space input ?

Thanks .

Edit

HTML Content :

```html
<p><em>Lorem ilolosum </em>dolor sit amet, consectetur adiloloiscing elit. Mauris tortor felis, volutpat sit amet maximus nec, tempus auctor diam. Nunc odio elit,  commodo quis dolor in, sagittis scelerisque nibh. Susloloendisse consequat, sapien sit amet pulvinar  tristique, augue ante daloloibus nulla, eget gravida turpis est sit amet nulla. Vestibulum lacinia mollis  accumsan. Vivamus loloorta cursus libero vitae mattis. In gravida bibendum orci, id faucibus felis molestie ac.  Etiam vel elit cursus, scelerisque dui quis, auctor risus.</p>
```

Comment: Please provide a example of content.

Comment: @Shiva Done. This is a simple lorem ipsum wrapped in a <p> content

Comment: Please provide a example of content with horizontal and vertical space...

Answer (score 0):

For the horizontal space, you can use the meta sequence `\s` to find any space character like this:

```
content = content.replace(/\s{2,}/gm, ' ') //horizontal spaces
```

For the "vertical space" (it's juste a new line), juste remove the element:

```
content = content.replace(/<p><br><\/p>/gm, '') //Vertical spaces
```

Comment: Thanks. However i still can't remove additional vertical spaces because de regex does not work when i'm tryng to grab more than one in my regex`content = content.replace(/<p><br><\/p>{2,}/gm, '')` . It's works only when i don't use quantifier. How to get it work ?